# Docker Windows how to keep container running without login?

Tags: docker, windows-server

I have Docker installed inside a Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2016.

I have a Linux Container from Python3 with NGINX server using `--restart=always` param, it runs fine while I am logged in, if I restart the VM, the container is no longer active, and it starts only if I log in.

Also if I logout, the container stops.

**How can I make a container run as a service without login and keep it running on logout?**

Comment: are you sure the dockerd service runs on your VM when not logged in? what version of docker did you install in detail?

Comment: I have other Administrator accounts that can verify the service is running, I do not have `dockerd` as in linux, but I have Docker Desktop Service running even if the session is closed or not logged in.

Comment: I don't think Docker Desktop is the right for containers on Windows Server. See my answer. can you provide a docker info and details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I went through quite a lot of pain in order to make this work, here is a solution that worked for me for running a linux container using docker desktop on a windows 10 VM.

First, read [this](https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2018/08/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/?doing_wp_cron=1560773237.7298181056976318359375) page to understand a method for running a python script as a windows service.

Then run your container using powershell and give it a name e.g

```
docker run --name app your_container
```

In the script you run as a service, e.g the main method of your winservice class, use `subprocess.call(['powershell.exe', 'path/to/docker desktop.exe])` to start docker desktop in the service. Then wait for docker to start. I did this by using the docker SDK:

```
client = docker.from_env()
started = False
while not started:
    try:
        info = client.info()
        started = True
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

When client has started, run your app with subprocess again

```
subprocess.call(['powershell.exe', 'docker start -interactive app'])
```

Finally ssh into your container to keep the service and container alive

```
subprocess.check_call(['powershell.exe', 'docker exec -ti app /bin/bash'])
```

Now install the service using `python service.py install`

Now you need to create a service account on the VM that has local admin rights. Go to Services in windows, and find your service in the list of services. Right click -> properties -> Log On and enter the service account details under "This account". Finally, under general, select automatic(delayed) start and start the service.

Probably not the most 'by the book' method, but it worked for me.

Comment: Great method, the only thing I changed is the service login account, because if I set "This account", when I logout the service stops, so I used a SYSTEM account to keep it alive. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've got a better answer from [HERE](https://thecodeframework.com/start-docker-desktop-on-windows-start-up-without-user-logon/)

The summary is to build a Task and assign it to `Task Scheduler` to run on Windows start.

## All the scripts should be run on powershell

1. Logon to the windows server/machine where you want the Docker services to start automatically.
2. Create a file called startDocker.ps1 at your location of choice and save the following script inside it:

```powershell
start-service -Name com.docker.service
start C:\'Program Files'\Docker\Docker\'Docker Desktop.exe'
```

Verify that the location of Docker.exe is correct on your machine otherwise modify it in the script accordingly.

3. Create a file called registerTask.ps1 and save the following script inside it.

```powershell
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup`
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-File C:\PowershellScripts\startDocker.ps1"
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8 -AllowStartIfOnBatteries
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Start Docker on Start up" -Settings $settings -User "Your user" -Password "Your user password" -RunLevel Highest

# This is needed so that this user has access to docker services
try 
{
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group docker-users -Member "Your user" -ErrorAction Stop
} 
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberExistsException] { }
```

4. Modify the script: You will have to change a couple of things in the scripts above according to your computer/server.

In the `$action` line, change the location of `startdocker.ps1` script file to where you have placed this file.

In the `Register-ScheduledTask` line change the account user and password to an account user that needs Docker services to be started at the Windows start-up.

5. Execute registerTask.ps1

Open Windows Powershell as Administrator and set the current directory to where you have placed `registerTask.ps1`. For example

```powershell
cd C:\PewershellScripts\
```

Next execute this script as follows

```powershell
.\registerTask.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of docker did you install exactly / in detail?

The procedure to get docker running on a server is very different than for desktops!
It's purely script based as described in detail in the [MS virtualization docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server)

The executable name of the windows-server docker EE (enterprise) service is by the way indeed dockerd as in linux.

Comment: I have Docker Desktop for Windows 18.09.2 installed and running
I already tried with docker EE as the docs said, but I think it is not possible to run Linux containers with it, or at least I haven't found how to.

Comment: of course it is not possible to run Linux containers without a hypervisor running a Linux kernel(the way Docker Desktop works for developing purposes). Your original question was not mentioning a Linux based container and asking for a reason why the containers are only running when you're logged in. This is what my answer refers to!

Comment: So, there is no way to run Linux containers on windows with docker EE?

Comment: there is some, but afaik not really mature and may be coming more but why? you add complexity! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers